# Angular2 routing - url doesn't change and page doesn't load

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc, angular2-routing

I've started learning angular2 with typescript and I'm trying to implement a route of book/:id but my route doesn't change and the html doesn't neither.

I have this file called app.module.ts which has all my other routes which work:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UniversalModule } from 'angular2-universal';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component'
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';
import { BookComponent } from'./components/book/book.component';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        BookComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        UniversalModule, // Must be first import. This automatically imports BrowserModule, HttpModule, and JsonpModule too.
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'book/:id', component: BookComponent },
            { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
            { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ])
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

My book component which uses ngOnInit to get id from url

**book.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LibraryService } from '../../services/app.service.library';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'book',
    template: require('./book.component.html'),
    providers: [LibraryService]
})
export class BookComponent {
    book: any;

    constructor(private libraryService: LibraryService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        // prints to console id e.g. 1
        console.log(this.route.snapshot.params["id"]);
        this.libraryService.getBook(this.route.snapshot.params["id"])
            .subscribe(response => this.book = response);
    }
}
```

If I type the url in the browser "http://localhost:60369/book/1" I get this stack trace error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'id' of undefined at
>   AppView._View_BookComponent0.detectChangesInternal
>   (BookComponent.ngfactory.js:27:82) at AppView.detectChanges
>   (C:\Users\GOWDY_N\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\MyAngular2App\MyAngular2App\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:9566:18)
>   at AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges
>   (C:\Users\GOWDY_N\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\MyAngular2App\MyAngular2App\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:9592:23)
>   at AppView._View_BookComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal
>   (BookComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:32:8) at AppView.detectChanges
>   (C:\Users\GOWDY_N\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\MyAngular2App\MyAngular2App\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:9566:18)
>   at AppView.detectContentChildrenChanges
>   (C:\Users\GOWDY_N\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\MyAngular2App\MyAngular2App\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:9584:23)
>   at AppView.detectChangesInternal (C:\Users\GOWDY_N\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2015\Projects\MyAngular2App\MyAngular2App\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:9576:18)
>   at AppView.detectChanges (C:\Users\GOWDY_N\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\MyAngular2App\MyAngular2App\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:9566:18)
>   at AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges
>   (C:\Users\GOWDY_N\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\MyAngular2App\MyAngular2App\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:9592:23)
>   at AppView.detectChangesInternal (C:\Users\GOWDY_N\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2015\Projects\MyAngular2App\MyAngular2App\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:9577:18)

Also if I try to navigate to the book page from the home screen, my console.log works in ngOnInit but the url doesn't change and the new content doesn't load.

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LibraryService } from '../../services/app.service.library';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    template: require('./home.component.html'),
    providers: [LibraryService]
})
export class HomeComponent {
    books: Array<any>;

    constructor(private libraryService: LibraryService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.libraryService.getBooks().subscribe(response => {
            this.books = response;
        });
    }
}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Book Store</h1>

    <div id="custom-search-input">
        <div class="input-group col-md-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Book title, author, etc" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="button">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let book of books" style="list-style-type: none; padding: 10px;" class="col-md-4 hvr-curl-top-left">
            <div class="card" style="border-color: black; border-style: solid; border-width: thin; padding: 5px;">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <h3 class="card-title">{{book.title}}</h3>
                    <p class="card-text">{{book.description}}</p>
                    <a href="#" [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']" class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/book', book.id]">More details</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Clicking on this link:

```
<a href="#" [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']" class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/book', book.id]">More details</a>
```

Doesn't give me a stack trace error but the new content doesn't load and the url stays the same. I also get a console.log message within book.component.ts and library service works as well.

I can't see what I'm missing.

Comment: Did you test your code on whether that id value exists or not? Do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.route.snapshot.params["id"]));` as first thing on ngOnInit to see if you have the value.

Comment: @echonax If I click on the link from the home page, console.log works in ngOnInit but the url doesn't change. If I manually type the url I get a stack trace. I'm going to update my post so you can see what I am talking about.

Comment: I know what you mean and I can guess the reason why you are getting the stacktrace but if it's what I think, you should get the habit of debugging your code. So please insert the console.log. If the code isn't reaching to oninit then try it on the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I made some progress with my initial problem. Because I'm learning angular2 and everything that I can do with it, I originally wrote the code to use subscribe when the user goes from the home page to the book page with url book/1 for example.

However I've now changed the way I'm using subscribe because I was getting a template error.

I was using this before on ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.libraryService.getBooks().subscribe(response => {
        this.books = response;
    });
}
```

But now I've changed it to this:

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            const id = params["id"];
            this.book = this.libraryService.getBook(id);
        });
    }
```

Using subscribe now feels a bit redundant because because it's just a simple api call, I don't have to observe anything in my angular code.

I'll leave this answer here for now but if anyone has a better answer with an explanation I'll mark their answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to directly access the router params, this might causing the undefined as the page loads.

Try saving it to a local variable like:

```
 let params: Params = this.route.snapshot.params;
```

After that execute the code on params[]