# Angular 8 - URL loads with routerLink but doesn't show when directly access in the browser in LOCALHOST

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-routerlink, routelink

I have developed the Angular 8 application and I am using the routerLink to navigate the components which work fine without any issue but when I enter the same URL directly in the browser it doesn't show anything and in the console, I am seeing the errors as below

[image]

For Example, I open the homepage http://localhost:4200/home and I have added the routerLink here to go to http://localhost:4200/about and I will be able to view successfully but if I enter the URL http://localhost:4200/about directly in the ULR nothing shows

I have taken care of the app-routing.model.ts

```
const routes: Routes =
    [
        { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
        { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
        { path: '**', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
    ];
    @NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

And I have header.component.ts to handle the navigation bar so I have added the 
`<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the header.component.html
and then I have included the selector of header.component.ts in app.component.ts
`<app-header></app-header>` and then in finally index.html I have included the selector of app.component.ts i.e `<app-root></app-root>`

Can you please tell me if there is something wrong.

Before asking this question I have gone through below and nothing helps

1. [RouterLink does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832851/routerlink-does-not-work)
2. [Angular 2 Routing Does Not Work When Deployed to Http Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43535048/angular-2-routing-does-not-work-when-deployed-to-http-server)
3. [Angular2 routing - url doesn't change and page doesn't load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41694396/angular2-routing-url-doesnt-change-and-page-doesnt-load)

Comment: Could you please share the template of your AppComponent?

Comment: Hello, @WillAlexander I have updated the question with details as it was a bit explanatory, thanks !!

Comment: And I am seeing the errors as `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` in the console when I directly access the URL

Comment: Have you tried restarting the development server? Have you modified the `base href` at all? Have you tried putting your `router-outlet` in the AppComponent template, as that would make more sense?

Comment: Yeah I have tried putting the router-outlet to app.component and also I have ` <base href="/">` in the index.html file and still the same  issue

Comment: How do you start your server?

Comment: I am using `ng serve` to start in the local system, It was well working before initially and not sure what changed suddenly

Comment: And I know many people suggested to use hash in the router module like `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],`, this will work but I don't want to keep # in the URL and my app was working previously without hash aswell

Comment: @JBNizet , Did you find anything suspicious?

Comment: I was wondering if you were actually using the CLI or not. Are you sure you don't have any compilation issue?

Comment: No surpsrisely I don't see any compilation issue

Comment: I supouse you import the AppRoutingModule in your app.module

Comment: Did you find a solution, without using the hash?

Answer (score 8):

On server we can use hashStrategy for routing.

In routing file just replace `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)` to  `RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{useHash : true})`.

Comment: Simple, effective solution

Comment: Thanks Guy, It solved my problem after much searching on google.

Answer (score 0):

for apache server you can add .htaccess file

```html
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

We have to make sure that inside index.html base href is

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little odd, but I had a trailing space in a **cssclass="class class2 "**